# String.Content como fazer não ser sensível a maiúsculas e minusculas

Tags: c#

Boas eu tenho uma string em que quero pesquisar se existe uma palavra, mas não sendo sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas

Exemplo:

```
string tt2 = "teste amanha de manha";
string pp = "Amanha";
if (tt2.Contains(pp))
{
//Não entra na condição pois na string o amanha tem o "a" em minusculo
}
```

Comment: você pode colocar a `string`em caixa alta ou baixa com `string.ToUpper()` ou `string.ToLower()`

Comment: @JcSaint gambiarra. Funciona só por coincidência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o método `Contains` não é possível, mas pode-se ter o resultado esperado com o método `IndexOf`

```
string tt2 = "teste amanha de manha";
string pp = "Amanha";
if (tt2.IndexOf(pp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
{
    //agora ele entra aqui
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, simples e eficaz, obrigado!